Как для каждого клиента определить, когда он перестал платить с помощью логики case в postgreSQL?
Как для каждого клиента определить, когда он перестал платить?
Я пробовал:
case when next_paid_month is null then user_id end as stopped_paing_user_id

Но таким образом за последний месяц в данных все клиенты считаются таковыми, что не так.
Другой вариант:
case when next_paid_month is null 
     and payment_month =! Last_payment_month
     then user_id end as stopped_paying_user_id

Таким образом последний месяц исключается, что меня не устраивает.
Как следует прописать условие, чтобы пользователи, от которых не было платежей в последний месяц также учитывались?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?

Нужен пример данных в таблице и желаемый результат на основе этих данных

Ну, что-нибудь типа left join <ваша_таблица> t1 on t.user_id=t1.user_id and t1.payment_month=Last_payment_month и в case проверять дополнительно на то, что t1.user_id is null. Но лучше структуру таблицы бы посмотреть

А просто MAX(last_payment) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) чем не устраивает?

Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL? Особенно пункты 5 и 3.
